# How to configure ftp-proxy.conf?

Tags: proxy, ftp

How can I configure the service ftp-proxy correctly? I have set Listen por to local (127.0.0.1:port) but when service is started, it does not shows in Listen ports with command "netstat -an", I've had tried with following sentences:

Listen         ip_address:port_number
listen_address ip_address:port_number

This is in Ubuntu v22.04